# After rotating the screen to clockwise (portrait mode), the mouse, touch screen calibration is lost

Tags: xorg

When I rotated the screen to fit the screen layout, all the mouse cursor inputs are lost. This is a brand new HP EliteOne 800 all-in-one touch PC.

Any idea how to fix the mouse/touch screen inputs?

[image]

Comment: You know where to report bugs, no?

Comment: What have you tried? [this](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=107167) or [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=996830)?

Answer (score 1):

If the calibration goes wrong also after reboot, I would say this looks like a bug.
I sometimes have problems with my mouse pointer when changing video modes, switching to terminal mode (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>) and back to graphical mode (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>) resets my mouse in those cases. Maybe this will also reset your calibration.